# Functional interface to pass any method as parameter in Java

Tags: java, methods, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to write a method that takes in 2 parameters - a class reference, and a reference of a method in that class. The return type of the method itself should be whatever that class's method return type is. For example:

```
public <T> T myMethod (Class<?> c, <reference to a method m in class c>), where m returns something of type <T>.
```

That is, in my code I should be able to call the above method as:

```
myMethod (SomeClass.class, x -> x.someMethod(param1, param2))
```

Note that `SomeClass` can be any class, and `someMethod` can be any method in that class with any number of parameters.

I am reasonably sure this is possible using lambda and functional interface in Java 8, but not entire clear on how to put it.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. For one, you can't directly call a method unless it's either static, in which case doing this makes no sense, or you have an instance. The only time this is useful is when the method itself is private, in which case using Reflection is your only option

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe someone can provide a better option with some background

Comment: The methods I am going to call are not static. I am doing this to be able to perform a  common operation on all these methods without using AOP or proxy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The functional interface method needs to take one argument of the same type as the named class `c`, so you need to define a generic type for that class, lets call it `C`.

The functional interface method needs to return a value of type `T`, but lets rename it `R` to represent the return type.

This means that your function interface can be: `Function<C, R>`

Your full method declaration is then:

```
public <C, R> R myMethod(Class<? extends C> clazz, Function<C, R> method)
```

It can be called exactly like you showed.

*Demo*

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        String param1 = "Foo", param2 = "Bar";

        String result = t.myMethod(SomeClass.class, x -> x.someMethod(param1, param2));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
    public <C, R> R myMethod(Class<? extends C> clazz, Function<C, R> method) throws Exception {
        C obj = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        return method.apply(obj);
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass() {}
    public String someMethod(String param1, String param2) {
        return param1 + " + " + param2 + ": " + this;
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Foo + Bar: test.SomeClass@5594a1b5
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. Thank you @Andreas.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do isn't immediately possible. Meaning, you can't reference a method without having a direct reflective access to it.

Effectively, `myMethod(MyClass.class, myClass -> myClass.Hello)` is definitely not 
 a good solution to anything. Think about it, where would you need this? If the method was static, you could invoke it anyways, and if it wasn't, you'd only need an instance.

What you can do, however, is find your method and invoke it through the reflection api:

```
public Object myMethod(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.getDeclaredMethod("name_of_method", ... /*Any parameters*/).invoke(/*params*/);
}
```